# Execute conditions (Filters) one by one in MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm working on a query where i'm using $and to use multiple filters or conditions. when i explain the query so i found that $and is not working like javaScript && operator. How can i achieve JavaScript && like functionality in mongoDB query?

```
MyModel.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    $and: [{
      $text: {
        $search: mappedSearchTxt
      }
    }, ...regexFilter, ...filters]
  }
}])
```

Comment: Please show the query you're using

Comment: my query look like this 
MyModel.aggregate([
   {
    $match: {
     $and: [
      { $text: { $search: mappedSearchTxt } },
      ...regexFilter,
      ...filters
     ]
    }
   }
  ])

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant info instead of posting it in a comment. I've added it for you.

Comment: thank you @ChrisG, i don't use stack overflow that much so i had no idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Example document

```
{ 
  _id: '1234'
  name: 'John',
  age: 34,
  father: 'Andy'
}
```

Your $and query should look like - `$and: [{ .... }]`

```
.find({ $and: [{ name: 'John'}, { father: 'Andy' }])
```

The above is just a demostration of $and, because the following query works the same.

```
.find({ name: 'John', father: 'Andy' })
```

Comment: so it'll use condition on name 1st and then father?

Comment: it's &&, so there's no sequence. it's like APPLE && ORANGE, and ORANGE && APPLE, in the end you get both fruits, there's no sequence.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: i just want to achieve JavaScript && like functionality. if we have statement Cond1 && Cond2 && Cond3 so here if Cond2 will be false so JS will not check for Cond3, it'll make the entire statement false. Same thing i want to achieve in MongoDB that conditions get execute after one by one.

Comment: Well, it's exactly the same, if only one condition matches, while the other 2 doesn't, the query will return null / empty array. Does sequence matter?  i guess not. Is it tested in sequences? I'm not sure because it's not in the docs